# Override a border without moving it

Tags: html, css, border, nav

I would like add a `border-bottom` that displays when I hover over it with the mouse. I want it to override the border underneath so it looks like it changes colour. An example of this can be found here http://www.formaplex.com/services (in the nav bar)

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ey006ftg/

Also, a small question: does anyone know why there is a small gap in-between the the links (can be seen when hovering from link to link) and how to get rid of it.

Thanks

Comment: You should avoid selector like nav ul li a, it's not efficient, and give too much priority to that selector. Put your transition in the initial selector, not the :hover, that way the animation will be in both way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative margin to overlay the border below, as shown:

```css
nav {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:0;
}
nav ul {
  width: 1056px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1056px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17%;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 21px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: orange;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-bottom: solid orange 3px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As for [fighting the inline gap](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), seeing as you defined a font-size later for the `a` tag, I would just add a `font-size:0`, which I added to `nav` in the above Snippet.

Comment: @SuperDavid You're very welcome, if this was the answer you were looking for, you can mark it as 'accepted' by click the grey (will become green) tick under my score for this answer. This helps others know that your problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css:

```
nav a {
    border-bottom: solid transparent 3px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/ey006ftg/1/

Comment: Or you can add it to your existing `nav ul li a` css too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I never knew the transparent attribute even existed, I am still a css novice

Comment: Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the correct answer if it help you solve your issue David.

Answer (score 0):

***[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wk35c2jt/)***

Simply set your **default border to transparent** - change color on hover

```
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 21px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: solid transparent 3px; /* add this! */
    transition:0.3s; /* or even this :) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey006ftg/3/)

To set `border-bottom` the way you want, you have to add border to anchor tag like this:

```
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 21px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

and to make sure the space between menu items is gone use a little fix adding negative margin to your `li` tags inside menu like this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17%;
    margin-right: -4px;

}
```